# PL/SQL subtract collection

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have 2 collection variables var1 and var2 in my pl/sql function.
For example, the data inside of them is:

```
var1           var2
X              X
X
Y
```

How can I subtract with pl/sql these collections so the result of it will be like:

```
var1 - var2:       var2 - var1
X                  empty
Y
```

My collection type definition is below:

```
create type MY_TYPE_OBJECT as (
id                  numeric(20,0),
string_val          varchar(4000),
time                timestamp)

create domain MY_TYPE_TABLE as MY_TYPE_OBJECT[];
```

my variables are of MY_TYPE_TABLE type.

Comment: Suppose the types are defined correctly. We are working with collections of objects with 3 attributes. What are the real values in your collections and what is the real expected outcome of the collections subtraction? In your examples you're working with scalar values, yet you defined collections of compound types. Where's the truth?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your collections are of the same data type, in PL/SQL you can do it extremely easily as

```
var1 multiset except var2
var2 multiset except var1
```

**Example:**

```
declare
    var1                sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt := sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt('X','X','Y');
    var2                sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt := sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt('X');

    var1_minus_var2     sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt;
    var2_minus_var1     sys.ora_mining_varchar2_nt;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('var1 has '||var1.count()||' elements');
    for i in nvl(var1.first(),1)..nvl(var1.last(),0) loop
        dbms_output.put_line('    element '||i||' = '||var1(i));
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('var2 has '||var2.count()||' elements');
    for i in nvl(var2.first(),1)..nvl(var2.last(),0) loop
        dbms_output.put_line('    element '||i||' = '||var2(i));
    end loop;

    var1_minus_var2 := var1 multiset except var2;

    dbms_output.put_line('var1_minus_var2 has '||var1_minus_var2.count()||' elements');
    for i in nvl(var1_minus_var2.first(),1)..nvl(var1_minus_var2.last(),0) loop
        dbms_output.put_line('    element '||i||' = '||var1_minus_var2(i));
    end loop;

    var2_minus_var1 := var2 multiset except var1;

    dbms_output.put_line('var2_minus_var1 has '||var2_minus_var1.count()||' elements');
    for i in nvl(var2_minus_var1.first(),1)..nvl(var2_minus_var1.last(),0) loop
        dbms_output.put_line('    element '||i||' = '||var2_minus_var1(i));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

... yields the output of ...

```
var1 has 3 elements
    element 1 = X
    element 2 = X
    element 3 = Y
var2 has 1 elements
    element 1 = X
var1_minus_var2 has 2 elements
    element 1 = X
    element 2 = Y
var2_minus_var1 has 0 elements
```

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work for me. I get an error: PLS-00306 wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_EXCEPT_ALL'. when I call v_1 := v1_tmp  MULTISET EXCEPT v2_tmp; (all of variables are variables the same type)

Comment: I'll add collection type definition to a question. Done

Comment: @AndreyS, your type definitions are clearly not for Oracle DB.

Comment: but it's oracle for sure

Comment: @AndreyS, The syntax of the types creation is wrong.

Comment: @AndreyS, I may have found a solution, but before I post it, you'll have to cooperate fully and make your question text absolutely exact. I'd like to avoid iteratively answering badly phrased questions.